# What's wrong with my PHP/JSON code?

Tags: php, json

I've been working with the ESPN API and my goal is to parse specific values from a JSON object and save them to a localized file. I am running my program through the command line, so no errors are evident, especially to me--a novice at PHP. I already ran code that achieves the same goal in Javascript, but switched over to PHP because I needed to write to a localized file, something impossible with client-side scripting. Therefore, I am positive that the paths of the JSON array I am entering are valid. Below, I will include the PHP script, as well as a snippet of the ESPN JSON object. Lastly, please do not report the question due to the question at hand being too localized. I do not know specifically what the issue is, but once the question is answered, I will rename and reformat the post accordingly to help other users in the future with the same type of problem.

PHP Script

```
<?php

$url = file_get_contents("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes?apikey=<sensitive>");
$data = json_decode($url, true);
$path = $data->sports[0]->leagues[0]->athletes;
$length = count($path);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $name = $data->sports[0]->leagues[0]->athletes[$i]->fullName;
    file_put_contents("Users/<sensitive>/Desktop/athletes.txt", $name);
}

?>
```

ESPN API JSON Object Snippet

```
{
sports: [
{
name: "football",
id: 20,
uid: "s:20",
leagues: [
{
name: "National Football League",
abbreviation: "nfl",
id: 28,
uid: "s:20~l:28",
groupId: 9,
shortName: "NFL",
athletes: [
{
id: 14856,
firstName: "Isaako",
lastName: "Aaitui",
fullName: "Isaako Aaitui",
displayName: "Isaako Aaitui",
shortName: "I. Aaitui",
...
}
```

Comment: You're not actually describing what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using json_decode with the second parameter set to true which means the return value is an array, not an object.

you have:

```
$data = json_decode($url, true);
$path = $data->sports[0]->leagues[0]->athletes;
```

you should have:

```
$data = json_decode($url, true);
$path = $data['sports'][0]['leagues'][0]['athletes'];
```

Comment: Also, you probably could just do

`$name = $path[$i]['fullName']`

Comment: Worked! Had to switch a few things up. Thanks so much :)